# X11 Forwarding for non-root user not working

Tags: vagrant, macos-high-sierra, x11-forwarding, ubuntu-18.04

[Cross-Posted](https://askubuntu.com/q/1029909/128912)

### Environmental Details

Relevant bits of server's /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost no
```

Relevant bits of client's $HOME/.ssh/config:

```
Host *
    XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth
    ForwardX11 yes
    ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

Using XQuartz on macOS High Sierra.

### The Problem

I'm spinning up a vagrant Ubuntu 18.04 VM. I've added a second user outside of the `vagrant` user.

```
ssh -X vagrant@ubuntu-bionic xclock
```

I can get X11Forwarding to work when I login as the `vagrant` user. I cannot get X11Forwarding to work when I login as the `ops` user.

```
ssh -X ops@ubuntu-bionic xclock

X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
Error: Can't open display:
```

I want to be able to get it to work with the `ops` user. From the client, `$DISPLAY` has a value. When I login with `vagrant`, `$DISPLAY` has a value. When I login as `ops`, `$DISPLAY` is unset. If I set `$DISPLAY` to match what it is with the `vagrant` user, I get the same error:

```
Error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0
```

when `X11UseLocalhost yes`

```
Error: Can't open display: ubuntu-bionic:10.0
```

when `X11UseLocalhost no`

If I login as `ops` and then `sudo su - vagrant`, `$DISPLAY` remains unset. If I login as `vagrant` and then `sudo su - ops`, `$DISPLAY` is inherited.

What am I missing to get this to work? I've run `xhost +` in each user (including `sudo -s root xhost +`) and it still doesn't work.

If I add `-vv` to my ssh commands, I see this message when connecting as `vagrant`:

```
X11 forwarding request accepted on channel 0
```

and as `ops`:

```
Remote: X11 forwarding disabled in user configuration file.
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
```

Comment: On the ubuntu machine, what is in the `~ops/.ssh/config` file?  (ie, in `/home/ops/.ssh/config`) any differences between that and the one in the `vagrant` users' home dir?

Comment: The server `vagrant`/`ops` home directories don't currently have a `~/.ssh/config` file.

Comment: Now both `vagrant`/`ops` have the contents of the `~/.ssh/config` referenced at the top of the post. Still not working.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get the whole topic, but for my very similar situation it helped to create the user`s`~/.Xauthority`file. I copied it from the vagrant user`s home directory and then set the new ownership.

Comment: If you install `xauth` the file will be created and populated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

On macOS BigSur with `XQuartz 2.8.1` (xorg-server 1.20.11):

Setting the following into my `Vagrantfile` solved it for me (for `ubuntu 20.04`):

```
  config.vm.provision "shell",
    inline: "apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install xauth -y"
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true
  config.ssh.forward_x11 = true
```

The whole Vagrantfile would be:

```
Vagrant.require_version ">= 2.2.3"

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v, override|
    override.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-20.04"
  end
  config.vm.provision "shell",
    inline: "apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install xauth firefox firefox-geckodriver -y"
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true
  config.ssh.forward_x11 = true
end
```

Allows running `firefox -no-remote https://stackoverflow.com/` through the X server.
The [`-no-remote` flag](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments) is added since it seems to reduce the latency.

As inspired by a guide on [How to enable and use SSH X11 Forwarding on Vagrant Instances](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-enable-and-use-ssh-x11-forwarding-on-vagrant-instances/) by Josphat Mutai.